# How to bind a cookie value to a pojo field in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

For example, I'd like to bind the value of the cookie in the current request to the pojo below.

```
@RequestMapping(path="/", method= GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> handleTheRequest(Foo foo){
    return blah;
}

public class Foo{
    private string cookieValue;
    //Other fun fields

    public void setCookieValue(String value){ 
        this.cookieValue = value;
    }

   public string getCookieValue(){
        return cookieValue;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try ?

```
@RequestMapping(path="/", method= GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> handleTheRequest(@RequestBody Foo foo){
    return blah;
}
```